# MySQL Chained Inequality

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL doesn't complain when "chained inequality" syntax is used in a query's `WHERE` clause, but produces a result that is different from a query of a similar spirit, written with proper syntax. So what query is it actually running and what constraints are being applied? And why doesn't it produce an error?

A simplistic example: Suppose I have a table in a MySQL database a table called User with an attribute called `score`.

I can write a query of the following form with chained inequality syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM User
WHERE 10 < score < 15;
```

and a query of the following form with proper syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM User
WHERE score > 10 AND score < 15;
```

with different results.

To repeat the questions:

1. What query is actually being run with the chained inequality? (Specifically, what are the constraints applied?)
2. Why doesn't MySQL produce an error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html):

> For operators that occur at the same precedence level within an
>   expression, evaluation proceeds left to right, with the exception that
>   assignments evaluate right to left.

MySQL will evaluate this as:

```
WHERE (10 < score) < 15
```

Because MySQL treats boolean values as numbers in a numeric context, the parenthesized part is turned into 0 or 1 (or `NULL` if `score` is `NULL`) for the subsequent comparison.  So, the result is always true.

I believe this explains both why MySQL doesn't produce an error and why you are getting different results from what you expect.

You have various options using `AND`, but this would be typical:

```
WHERE score > 10 AND score < 15
```