# MySQL WHERE clause usage

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause

MySQL
I was trying to get values of category_id in between 9 to Maximum category id (use sub-query), without using Max function.

I tried the MySQL query given below. It works for the latter part, i.e. it gives category_id uptil maximum category_id. But, it gives all category ids from the very beginning (1), i.e. it does not start from '9'.

```
SELECT columns 
FROM table_name 
WHERE (9 <= category_id <=  (
                 SELECT category_id 
                 FROM table_name 
                 ORDER BY category_id 
                 DESC LIMIT 1 )
       );
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't wish to use MAX?

Comment: [mre] [MySQL Chained Inequality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40220794/3404097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically your query is

```
SELECT { columns }
FROM table_name 
WHERE 9 <= category_id;
```

Your condition which uses subquery makes no sense - column value cannot be greater than maximal value in this column.

Comment: the answer is helpful. But what if the question explicitly asks to use 'subquery'? I am a beginner in SQL and this is a practice question assigned.

Comment: @RUBINA My opinion is: either do it well, or don't do it at all. It's better not to study at all than to learn to do things the wrong way.